# DataGridViewCellStyle.Padding Property not padding?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I've tried to add some padding between the cells of my `DataGridView`. Using this [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.padding(v=vs.110).aspx), I tried adding padding using `DataGridViewCellStyle.Padding`. But it's not being shown.

I'm including the code. I'm not binding the `DataGridView` but filling it through `dataGridView1_CellFormatting`, so maybe that could be the issue?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
public FormDgv()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    FillTable();
    SetDgvProperties();

}

public void SetDgvProperties()
{
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
    this.dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
    this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
    this.dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
    this.dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
    this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
    this.dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect;
    this.dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 64;
    this.dataGridView1.CellFormatting += dataGridView1_CellFormatting;
    this.dataGridView1.ColumnCount = (int)table.Compute("Max(columnCount)", "");
    this.dataGridView1.RowCount = 8;
    dataGridView1.Refresh();
    Padding newPadding = new Padding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    this.dataGridView1.RowTemplate.DefaultCellStyle.Padding = newPadding;
}

DataTable table;
public void FillTable()
{
    table = GetData(connString);
}

void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 & e.ColumnIndex >= 0)
    {
        string filter = string.Format("orderNum={0} AND ZeroBasedCol={1}", e.RowIndex + 1, e.ColumnIndex);
        var row = table.Select(filter).FirstOrDefault();
        if (row != null)
        {
            var color = (Color)new ColorConverter().ConvertFrom(row["ColorNotFilled"]);
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = color;
            e.CellStyle.SelectionBackColor = color;
            e.CellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.White;
            e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
            e.CellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you checked posted answers on this question?  :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I had to take a few sick days from work. I tested yesterday and RezaAghaei's answer worked well.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, by the way, you can also upvote for other answers if you find them useful. It's not compulsory at all, but it's good, because it motivates people to post useful answers and also it helps future readers to know about other useful or possible solutions. Currently I voted for the question and also for other answer  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usage of padding is providing some space between edge of cell and it's content. It does't have any impact on space between cells.

If you want to draw more thick grid lines between cells, you can handle [`CellPainting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting(v=vs.110).aspx) event and draw border around cell:

```
void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All);
    using (var pen = new Pen(this.dataGridView1.GridColor, e.CellStyle.Padding.All))
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, e.CellBounds);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Don't forget to add these lines of code to `Load` event:

```
this.dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Padding = new Padding(5);
this.dataGridView1.BackgroundColor = SystemColors.Control;
this.dataGridView1.GridColor = SystemColors.Control;
this.dataGridView1.CellPainting += dataGridView1_CellPainting;
```

Here is a screenshot of `DataGridView`:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are happy with a space that has the color of the grid lines you can set the size of the **Dividers** for all but the last `Columns` and `Rows`:

```
int space = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].DividerHeight = space;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1; i++) 
                    dataGridView1.Columns[i].DividerWidth = space;
dataGridView1.GridColor = Color.White;
```

[image]

Note that the `Dividers` are part of the `Rows` & `Columns`, so to keep control of the visial `Cell` sizes you need to factor them in your calculations or else the right/bottom cells will look bigger by one divider size!

Comment: Excellent! [`DataGridViewColumn.DividerWidth`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.dividerwidth(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`DataGridViewRow.DividerHeight`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.dividerheight(v=vs.110).aspx) are really useful.

Comment: It messed up my original layout a little; the dividers are part of the cell size, so either add them everywhere or calculate the right and bottom cells separately..